# Possible to open window without controls using anchor attributes?

Tags: html

Is it possible to open a new window without controls / scrollbar, etc using only a link or is javascript required to do that?  Not having much luck on a javascript-less solution.

something like

```
<a href="mysite.com/videoPlayer.php?v=1234" target="_blank" controls="false">Popout player</a>
```

No idea what the attributes might be, just wondering if this is possible.

We are being asked to produce a paste-able link that will behave similar to a flash based popout video player.  My guess is this isn't possible, but I wanted to make sure first.  They just want the video player inside a window without a restricted set of controls (no back button, refresh, editable address bar, etc).  I have control over what goes inside the window, I just won't be able to use javascript on the link.

Comment: what do you mean by  controls / scrollbar ?

Comment: @Sergio - backbutton, refresh, addressbar, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is required, because a href is a link to a resource and not a UI descriptor.

Comment: Makes sense.  I'll give it an hour or two just to make sure there's no obscure solution floating around before I mark this answered.